# How can I automatically close preview window after I move cursor to another window in Vim?

Tags: vim

I would like the preview window disappears automatically when cursor is not in the preview window or preview window loses the focus. Is it possible?

Comment: @sidyll No, I don't use Netrw. I wrote a client of twitter-like service in Vim, I use preview window to display timeline. Now I want the preview window closes automatically when cursor moves to another window.

Comment: Sorry, initially I though you were referring to the preview that netrw and also NERDTree have on files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to have a look on *autocommands*. A simple example would be:

```
autocmd WinLeave * pc
```

Which calls `pc` (close preview window) every time you leave a window. A more involved example could use a separate function that performs extra checking:

```
autocmd WinLeave * call ClosePreviewWindow()

function ClosePreviewWindow()
    if &pvw
        pclose
    endif
endfunction
```

Check `:h autocmd.txt` to learn more. This file has a complete listing of autocommand events in section 5, so you can choose the one that fits better.

Comment: Thank you, autocmd.txt is too long so I didn't read it before. BTW what's the meaning of "&" here?

Comment: @Vayn haha that's the only problem with Vim's help: too much information :-P The `&` is used to echo the option value. Any option should work. It kind of "converts" the option to a variable. You can try `:echo &tw` for example, which echoes the value of `tw`. Check `:h expr-option`