# PHP Vim autocomplete

Tags: php, vim, ide, autocomplete

I can not get the autocomplete to work for php files. I added the following to my .vimrc file but when I type `ctl + o` nothing happnens. When I type `ctl + x` i get `-- ^X` mode `(^]^D^E^F^I^K^L^N^O^Ps^U^V^Y)` at the bottom of vim.

```
filetype plugin on
autocmd FileType php set omnifunc=phpcomplete#CompletePHP
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you probably want is <kbd>Ctrl + x</kbd><kbd>Ctrl + o</kbd> in succession.

Incidentally, I map this to <kbd>Ctrl + Space</kbd> so as not to feel like I'm using Emacs.

Comment: also Ctrl + p and Ctrl + n are useful shortcutes to autocomlete words

Comment: @vsushkov Ctl+n will complete from words in current buffers, but not PHP functions and keywords.

Comment: yes, but ctrl +n also really useful. F.e. to complete variable names

Comment: both are very helpful. Thank you both.  After I run the ctrl+x ctrl+o It places the function syntax at the top of vim. That is really helpful but how do I remove that once I have finished with that function? It looks like this

mysql_connect([string server [, string username [, string password [, bool new_link [, int client_flags]]]]] | resource

~
[Scratch] [Preview]

I am almost ready to replace my current IDE with VIM!!!

Comment: @Stewy see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6113316/how-can-i-automatically-close-preview-window-after-i-move-cursor-to-another-windo

Comment: @Stewy or, what I use: `autocmd InsertLeave * if pumvisible() == 0|pclose|endif`  Whenever I leave insert mode, the preview window disappears

Comment: Thanks. Just found that as you posted... I didnt know that was called preview. Thanks for your help. I am just learning the powers of VIM

Comment: Michael Berkowski, what may i put in ~/.vimrc to accomplish the mapping you describe in the answer?

Comment: @Jonz I no longer have this mapping, but [here is a comprehensive answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510503/ctrlspace-for-omni-and-keyword-completion-in-vim)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `^P`, but I'm not sure.